# List of repositories that use github3 library

Tags: github3.py

I am moving to github3 after spending a lot of time on GitHub API v3 and also trying PyGithub. No doubt, github3 is super fast, uses GitHub rate limit extremely efficiently and closely resemble native GH API. I want a list of GitHub repositories that are currently using github3 which will help me and others a lot to use github3 in most efficient way.